# Falla en angular 1.7.8 - TypeError: v2.user_search is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, scope

llevo unos dias queriendo solucionarlo, bien en mi vista utilizo un formulario con:

```
<input type="search" class="autocomplete"  ng-model="user_search.search" ng-keyup="user_search(user_search.search)" autocomplete="off" >
```

Bien nada extraño, para mi controlador uso una funcion de scope

```
$scope.user_search = function(value) {
     $scope.user_search ="";
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url_server + "user/user_search",
        data: { consulta: value }

    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('this callback will be called asynchronously when the response is available');
        console.log(response.data);
        $scope.user_search = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('called asynchronously if an error occurs or server returns response with an error status.');
        console.log(response.data);
    });
```

el controlador funciona correctamente y la función se ejecuta al ingresar la primera letra (ng-keyup) , pero cuando ingreso la segunda letra de mi búsqueda me retorna este error

```
angular.js:15566 TypeError: v2.user_search is not a function
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:16417), <anonymous>:2:268)
at callback (angular.js:28950)
at Scope.$eval (angular.js:19392)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:19491)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:28954)
at defaultHandlerWrapper (angular.js:3823)
at HTMLInputElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3811)
```

que quede claro que es en la segunda+ vez que se ejecuta la función ya que la primera vez trae los datos del servidor y funciona correctamente

por el momento no he sido capaz de solucionarlo agradecería si pudieran orientarme

Answer (score 1):

En la primera linea tienes

```
$scope.user_search = function(value) {
```

y en la segunda tienes

```
$scope.user_search ="";
```

Estas sobreescribiendo tu propia variable y usando el mismo nombre tanto para `ng-model` y para `ng-keyup` que requieren cosas distintas.

Sólo tienes que usar una variable distinta para la función de busqueda y el ng-model

```
<input type="search" class="autocomplete" ng-model="user_search" ng-keyup="search(user_search)" autocomplete="off" >
```

Y en el código

```
$scope.search = function(value) {
    $scope.user_search ="";
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url_server + "user/user_search",
        data: { consulta: value }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('this callback will be called asynchronously when the response is available');
        console.log(response.data);
        $scope.user_search = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('called asynchronously if an error occurs or server returns response with an error status.');
        console.log(response.data);
    });
}
```

No deberías usar `key-up` para desencadenar llamadas http. Deberías usar [debounce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#debouncing-updates) para que el valor se actualize luego de unos segundos y observar los updates al valor de `ng-model` para desencadenar las llamadas http.

Comment: buena respuesta hermano, agregaría tener esto `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"` en el input search para evitar golpear al servidor en cada cambio

Comment: @fredyfx eso no tendrá efecto ya que de la forma que esta escrito la búsqueda se dispara en `key-up` así que si agregas eso sólo tendrás una búsqueda en cada tecla pero con un valor no actualizado. Sigue siendo valido aclararle eso al OP para que cambie el algoritmo. Gracias.